# Raising the bobbin thread doesn't work

Tags: sewing-machine

I am just learning my Singer Inspiration 4210 sewing machine. 
I've had some good luck with it so far, got some basic stitching done.

Then it jammed up on me, I had to pull it all out and tethered the bobbin and now I can't raise the bobbins thread. From what I can see, when I turn the wheel towards me, it's spinning around the bobbins but that piece doesn't grab the thread on my needle.

[image]

Little video of it not working. 
https://youtu.be/yPNt2UKMleU

Did we pull to hard and forced it out of wack? Is there an adjustment screw?

Comment: Is the bobbin in backwards, so the rotation is the wrong way? (That is BY FAR my most common problem.)

Comment: Rotates counter clockwise, I believe that's correct.

Comment: The wheel that spins around the bobbin is off sync. It sometimes clangs against the needle. Seems to catch the thread every once in a while. Looking into how to adjust.

Comment: My machine doesn't have a drop-in bobbin, so I can't even begin to troubleshoot, but I did a search for "singer sewing machine troubleshooting bobbin not catching" and a number of articles that looked fairly promising popped up.  I also did a search for with your particular singer model number and bobbin troubleshooting, and there was at least one article that was specifically about fixing the bobbin on your machine model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much searching, reading and watching videos I figured it out. I took the machine apart to adjust the "needle timing" (key words to search for). Sadly there is no video or instructions for this model specifically, so I'll summarize here:

1. Remove the back cover
2. Remove the bobbin assembly, and the cover over the spinning hook mechanism
3. Note the gear on the bottom with 2 screws, loosen the screws just a little and the spinning hook will move freely.
4. Align the tip of the hook to start just above the hole of the needle.
5. Tighten screws and reassemble.

MAKE SURE your needle is on the upswing, not the down swing. Before reassembly, pull the wheel towards you to ensure it spins around freely. Also, if you adjust it to be left/center/right or zig zag, I recommend aligning the hook and the needle on the left.

Maybe i'll make a video....

Comment: Congrats for figuring it out.

Comment: Thank you for sharing how to adjust timing on a Singer machine. This is very appreciated